# `glmnet()` variable importance interpretation using `varImp()` and `vi_model()`

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, feature-selection, lasso, glmnet

I fitted a Lasso Logistic Regression model using `glmnet`

```
X = data.matrix(mtcars %>% dplyr::select(-vs))
y = mtcars$vs
CV_lasso = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", type.measure = "class")
```

I was trying to determine variable importance and came across two methods

```
CV_lasso$glmnet.fit %>% 
  varImp(lambda = CV_lasso$lambda.min, scale = F)
```

```
CV_lasso$glmnet.fit %>% 
  vi_model(s = CV_lasso$lambda.min)
```

- What actually is the importance measurement? If a variable has a higher score, does that make it more important?
- Why does `varImp()` give me importance as absolute values whilst `vi_model` gives retains the sign? Which one is a better measurement of variable importance?
- How can I describe the effects of the most important variables on my outcome variable?